How do I get lamports sent from a parsed transaction
How do I get the lamports sent in each transaction and why are there multiple transaction accounts on each message?
This is the code I have, but 'parsed' is typed as any in the SDK
const getTransactionSummary = (
  fromAddress: ParsedMessageAccount,
  transaction: ParsedTransactionWithMeta
) => {
  const {
    blockTime,
    transaction: { message },
  } = transaction;

  const parsedLamports = message.instructions
    .filter(isParsedInstruction)
    .map(({ parsed }) => parsed.info.lamports);

  return {
    address: fromAddress.pubkey.toBase58(),
    time: blockTime ? new Date(blockTime * 1000).toISOString() : null,
    amount: parsedLamports.reduce(add, 0),
    meta: transaction.meta?.err ?? null,
  };
};```


I think you can use getParsedTransaction function to get preBalance and postBalance of accounts in a transaction. From that you can calculate lamports sent.
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), { commitment: 'finalized' });

  const signature = "signature of the transaction you want to calculate";
  const txDetail = await connection.getParsedTransaction(signature, {
    commitment: "finalized",
  });
  console.log("account array: ", txDetail.transaction.message.accountKeys)
  console.log("post balances: ", txDetail.meta.postBalances)
  console.log("pre balances: ", txDetail.meta.preBalances)


What about the account array, is that just the two accounts?
Sorry I haven't been able to try it out. Just doesn't make sense why accountKeys is an array to me

Array accounts is all account is read or written in the transaction.These account can be System account, PDAs, user accounts, another program accounts,...
